# Facebook Flex Intergration

Tags: flash, apache-flex, facebook

I went through this tutorial (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/articles/flex_fbgraph_pt4.html) and got everything working, only to find out that the way that she showed how to do it doesn't really work any more. Something about the fbjsbridge.js file being converted to an import in the facebook api. Does anyone know how I can convert this application here into making it use the current version. I don't know a lot about the flex or facebook api, so the bit of fiddling I have done is breaking everything.

Also, I don't know if this is true for the new version too, but it seemed that the fbjsbridge.js way only worked with internet explorer. Other people had this same issue. Does anyone else have any kind of experience with that.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with FB in Flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer. With the FBJSBridge integrated into the api now, all you have to do is copy and paste an HTML file from their example page on code.google.com and it converts an existing game programmed in flex into a game that can be run on facebook. It was surprisingly simple, the html I used is in this link:

http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/source/browse/trunk/examples/Embedding/index%20(using%20js%20login).html

It worked out really well, hope it works for anyone else that finds this question and needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question, but a hint to a better way to go. 
From the official [FB docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/):

> Note: We don't recommend FBML for new developers. If you aren't
>   already using FBML, you should instead implement your application
>   within an iframe, using the JavaScript SDK and social plugins for
>   client-side integration with Facebook services.

In a case if you this way, and will use iframe approach, you will not need to use FBJS and any bridges just old [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) to call real JavaScript and you could forget about FBJS.